# Facebook scrollTo()

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having a very bizzare issue with Facebook's `scrollTo()`. Here's my relevant code:

```
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId  : 'APPID',
                status : true, // check login status
                cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
                oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
            });
            FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 5000 });
            //FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();              
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

        function scrollToQuestion(top) {
            FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, top);
        }
    </script>
```

Here's the bizzare issue, the code on it's own does NOT work. HOWEVER while using firebug and putting a breakpoint right on the `FB.Canvas.scrollTo(top, 0);` line than the functionality works. What's going on...?!

EDIT: Finally figured it out... for some odd reason top variable was coming in as a string of some sort. I had to change the call to the function like this:

```
var top = 0;
top = parseInt($('.top'"]').position().top);
scrollToQuestion(top);
```

This fixed my issue.

Comment: Where – or more specific, _when_ – are you calling that function `scrollToQuestion`? I suspect it might happen before the asynchronously loaded SDK is initialized … (Are you saying you’re not getting any errors in the console, or did you just neglect to look there?)

Comment: Ok The function is called on an anchor click event behind a document.ready. The only error I got in console was a permission issue with "___wrapper" on the Facebook all.js. However why would an error make a difference if the functionality works with a breakpoint?